# Can I make rest API for Unity with Firebase cloud functions and Firestore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to make rest api for my Firestore database for my Unity game.
I don't want to connect directly to database, because the game complex logic, I want to application logic is controlled on the server to avoid tampering on the client side.

So I want to every write and every read request through cloud functions!
It is okey?

Write function to Firestore database with cloud functions very simple:

*Cloud function serverless nodejs index.js:*

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   let data = {
       name: 'Los Angeless',
       state: 'CA',
       country: 'USA'
     };

     // Add a new document in collection "cities" with ID 'LA'
     let setDoc = db.collection('xy').doc(data.text).set(data);

     return { text : "ok" }  });
```

*Unity c#:*

```
   public void writeexample()
     {


         var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
         data["text"] = “example”;
         data[“xy”] = “example”;

         FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance.GetHttpsCallable(“helloWorld”)
 .CallAsync(data).ContinueWith((task) =>
 {
 if (task.IsFaulted)
 {
           // Handle the error...
 }
 else if (task.IsCompleted)
 {

         // DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

         IDictionary snapshot = (IDictionary)task.Result.Data;

         print(“Result:” + snapshot["text"]);

     }
 });

 }
```

It's working good.
But how to read database? (Not realtime, only once simple query.)

I read this: [Call functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) - cloud functions docs

And this: [Get data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) - Firestore docs

But I don't see, how to get data through cloud functions.
I don't want trigger, I would like to use cloud functions as rest api. So every read and write to Firestore database through cloud functions. Is it not possible? If possible, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a REST endpoint with Cloud Functions that returns data from Firestore. But I'd consider actually making it an HTTP-callable function, just like your current `helloWorld` function already is. HTTP-callable functions are a thin wrapper around regular REST/HTTP(S) functions, which makes them much easier to call from your application code.

For example, to read the `name` field from documents in the collection that your `helloWorld` is writing to, you'd do something like this in Cloud Functions:

```
exports.getNames = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    let querySnapshot = await db.collection('xy').orderBy("name").limit(3).get();
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      let names = querySnapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.data().name);
      return names;  
    } 
    else {
      return [];
    }
});
```

You'd then call it from a similar constructs as you now have from Unity:

```
FirebaseFunctions.DefaultInstance.GetHttpsCallable(“getNames”)...
```

Comment: Ehh, I don't know..
I try this:
exports.getNames = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    let querySnapshot = await db.collection('example').get();
    let names = querySnapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.data().name);
    return names;
});

Firebase log:
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at exports.getNames.functions.https.onCall (/srv/index.js:80:41)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

My Firestore database structure:
example collection -> autoid -> name: example

Comment: It looks like there were no results for the query in that case. I updated the code in my answer to handle that case.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too

Comment: I get result, and map the problem.
exports.getNames = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    let querySnapshot = await db.collection('xy').orderBy("name").limit(3).get();
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      let names = querySnapshot.documents.map((doc) => doc.data().name);
        console.log("ok");
      return names;
    }
    else {
         console.log("nook");
      return [];
    }
});
If I create xy collection, then log:
Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
If I delete xy collection, then console log: nook.